# Selenium IDE not clicking on an element

Tags: selenium, calendar, automation, selenium-ide

I have a calendar popup with buttons to navigate to the previous and the next month. Unfortunately, IDE is not able to click on either of the previous / next button. I used Firebug to identify the element XPath and since it doesn't throw an error of element missing, I suppose the element is detected but someone clicking doesn't do anything

The same popup has dates and IDE can click on those easily. So it should not be a problem of IDE not detecting the elements in popup.

Please let me know what additional details should I provide to help you guys figure this weird thing.

Cheers,
K

Comment: Can you share the HTML surrounding particular calender pop-up. Or share the URL.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Sometimes you need to use a WaitFor to ensure the element is on the page before attempting the click. Especially if it's a dynamic element.